# speed up work flow

Tags: techniques

Can anyone give me advice on how I might speed up my work flow on a similar project.

I had 400 voice prompts to record for a telephone system.
They had to be supplied with individual file names at 32,000 sample rate/mono.

I recorded the voiceover in a two to three hour session. He does 2- 3 takes of each prompt.
I generally try get the best take as the last one.
He voices the number along with the prompt.

When I edit I start at prompt 400 and work backwards to prompt 1.
I generally just have to top and tail the good take. I isolate the good take and drag it to the track 2 underneath.
I use some compression and limiting on this track.

When I had all 400 prompts isolated I started to bounce to disk each one.
They all had quite complicated file names that I could copy from excel and paste them into the bounce to disk file box. I also had to change the sample rate to 32000 on bounce to disk.
It is very time consuming and I wondered is there any obvious speed up to my work flow.

Answer (score 1):

I think bounce to disk is your biggest problem - you should be routing through a print track.  I'd also strongly advise the purchase of quickeys.

If I were you, I'd do the edit and output as follows:

- start at the beginning of the session, not the end.
- instead of bouncing to disk, route the track through an aux to a print track.  Put all of your processing on the edit track.
- highlight the good take.
- engage a quickey macro that does the following: command + T, then f12
- listen and read along as the file prints.
- create a quickey that jumps to your spreadsheet, copies a cell, advances to the next cell, jumps back to protools, does a shift + command + R to open a rename dialogue, pauses, then command + paste, pause, enter, command + s  (looks complex, but I've done it countless times)
- move on to highlight the next good take and repeat.

once you're through the whole project, highlight the printed track and export in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the track with the edited versions, use AudioSuite processing to apply the processing, then use Export Selected As Files to export the files in one go.  You will need to do some file renaming because AudioSuite will append the file names but you could do that with  a renaming utility at the end. Export Selected as Files will also cover the sample rate conversion too.

Answer (score 0):

What Mike said... although when we do these I don't AudioSuite the processing, just cause I like to be able to tweak in realtime. What I do is bus the tracks to a new track, and re-record to that track. You can rename the track to the filename and viola! When it's done, select the file and do the Export Selected as. Also if you're on Mac, then do check out A Better Finder Rename (Now just Better Rename) - will save much grief -getting rid of those pesky _01's and such including being able to rename multiple files from a file with a list of filenames. At $20.00 it's a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this for recording: http://www.audiofile-engineering.com/voxover/

Additionally, using a DAW that has real-time and batch bounce (and optionally also batch processing). I.e. not Pro Tools.

Comment: voxover is certainly interesting looking, but I can't find anyone who has used it.